# How to delete Field Mapping

Tags: import

How do you delete field mapping you saved?  Have done a lot of work and learning system and now built up a bunch I won't use again but can't find anywhere in guide/online how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 4):

Go to :

> Administer -> System Settings -> Import/Export Mappings

There you can find all existing mappings and you can delete unwanted mappings there.

Check below link for more details :

https://www.techpond.in/solved-how-delete-field-mapping-civicrm

Comment: Exactly - that should work.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this lately, as I did: It's under "Administer", "System Settings", and then "Import/export Mappings".